# Add dictionary to dictionary to make it look more JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, loops, dictionary

I have a dictionary which is created within a loop, and I need to append these dictionaries to another one simultaneously. 
Is it any elegant way to do it?

```
f_temp = df['Relevant findings'].values.tolist()[0:8]
f_list = [x for i, x in enumerate(f_temp) if i == f_temp.index(x)]
f_num_total = len(f_list)
f_rand = random.randrange(1, f_num_total+1)

def create_rep(arr, row_data, condname, modality):  # get findings
    params = []
    # to_json = []
    if condname == 'Mass' and modality == 'Mammography':
        for i in range(len(arr)):
            params += grab_data(row_data, 0, 14, 19)
            row_data += 1

 for i in range(f_rand):
            f = random.choice(f_list)
            if f == 'Mass':
                rep_temp = create_rep(iter_params_mass, row, f, r)          
        finding = {f: rep_temp}
        #and now I have no idea where to go

>>>{'Assymetry': {'Assymetry': ['Global asymmetry']}}
```

I would like to append results one by one in another dictionary, to make it look like:

```
{'Findings/s':
            {'Assymetry':
                 {'Assymetry': ['Global asymmetry']}},
            {'Mass':
                 {'Shape': ['Oval']}}
         }
```

Any ideas, or maybe a way to create nested JSON objects? I am iterating through a lot of loops, so I am not sure what is the best practice.

Comment: Do you want to have array of JSONs in `Finding` ?

Comment: show `create_rep` declaration and `f_list` contents

Comment: @gorros Yes, and then also append a result to the "parent" node. I am fetching data partially using a lot of functions and then I need to bring it all together somehow.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be over thinking this.

`Findings/s`'s value should be a list, then it  is possible to append every generated dictionary to it. I'm using [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) just so the first iteration will not need to check if `d['Finding']` already exists or not.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for i in range(f_rand):
    f = random.choice(f_list)
    if f == 'Mass':
        rep_temp = create_rep(iter_params_mass, row, f, r)        
    d['Findings/s'].append({f: rep_temp})
```

**Note**: if `f` is not `'Mass'` you'll get a `NameError` since rep_temp wouldn't be defined, you'll need to solve this.

Also, you reassign the return value of `create_rep` to `rep_temp` but `create_rep` doesn't return anything. So, unless this is not your full code, you will have some unexpected results.

Comment: And if I understand correctly, defaultdict may have have multiple values needed for creating expanded object, since it's a list, correct? So, if it holds ['Finding', 'Condition'] I can use every value to append just created dict?

Comment: @AliceJarmusch Not really. As explained in the docs I've linked to, `defaultdict` simply creates a default value instead of raising `KeyError`

Comment: Looks nice, just add some default value for `rep_temp` :)

Comment: @gorros I'd leave that to OP, but I edited the answer :)

Comment: Thanks, but here's raising another error: defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'Findings/s': [{'Calcifications': {'Typically benign': ['Coarse or “popcorn-like”'], 'Suspicious morphology': ['Fine pleomorphic'], 'Distribution': ['Diffuse']}}, {'Mass': {'Shape': ['Oval'], 'Margin': ['Indistinct'], 'Density': ['Equal density']}}]}) - I'm just trying to simply print the result, and that's not really what I'm looking for, but very close. If I have defaultdic holding list, ultimately, values are appending to the list, and I have to append them into the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you're looking for something like this:

```
finding = {}
for i in range(f_rand):
    f = random.choice(f_list)
    rep_temp = None
    if f == 'Mass':
        rep_temp = create_rep(iter_params_mass, row, f, r)          
    finding[f] = rep_temp
```

But I also think you want the last line within the if statement? Not sure how the rest of the loops would look.